# Is RavenDB a good fit for this concept?

Tags: database, architecture, ravendb

First, a caveat: I'm rather new to the concepts behind document databases, so this may be an entirely obvious question.

I need to design a system that maintains a deep hierarchical catalog of parts that make up highly-complex products. It will detail the physical components that make up each part - and each part can be components of other parts - all the way up to the final product. Like this:

```
Widget
 |- Sprocket
 |  |- A4 nut
 |  |- B15 screw
 |  |- Sprocket Backshell
 |- Flange
 |  |- A4 washer
 |  |- Flange Housing
 |- Widget Assembly
```

Widget in this example could then later be incorporated as a Part underneath some other Product.

Each product may contain tens-of-thousands to hundreds-of-thousands of parts and, each type of component has different, unrelated properties that must be maintained. These properties can include the connections between related parts.

We have a poorly-designed version of this system in place right now, in SQL Server, as a single flat table with about 120 columns and several million records. About 85% of the fields in this table are null. My job is to replace this with something more maintainable and efficient and less error-prone.

Building this efficiently in a relational database would mean normalization - in this case, having one table for each type of part. This would be something of a problem I suspect as there are hundreds of part types, and new part types with their own specific properties are added regularly.

I'd like to use RavenDB for this, as a document database would suit the dynamic nature of the parts, but I don't know if it'd be a good fit, or how I'd implement the system in terms of documents. The products themselves are the root objects, but because of their size I can't afford to store a product as a single document.

Is RavenDB a good fit for this concept? Are there any pointers on how best to represent it in documents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erik, whether a document database is a good fit in this situation and what kind of structure would be best depends on what kind of operations you want to do on this data.

You can certainly use RavenDB to persist your parts and products, but to answer the question if it is a good choice, you must answer the following question:

- What kind of queries do you need?
- What is more performance-critical to your system, reads or writes?
- Can you live with eventual consistency?
- Can you take adavantage of features like map/reduce indexes?
- etc.

Comment: This pretty much answers my question - I don't think RavenDB will be a good fit here. Eventually consistency will be a problem here - I had forgotten about that characteristic - and map/reduce won't help me much with this problem, I don't think. Shame - I like the dynamic schema nature of a document database for storing the parts data, but I don't think I'll be able to get the customer to sign off on maintaining two independent databases...

Comment: That's an interesting one. I find that in practice there are very few cases where you cannot live with eventual consistency, since most of the time you won't recognize any difference (ravens indexing is very fast, though it runs asynchronous) and even if - you can enforce consistency easily for those queries. I've built several business applications with RavenDB and didn't find this to be an issue (there are others). I don't see any reason why your customer would need to maintain to independent dbs. You can drop me an email if you want to follow-up on that.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a pretty good fit for a relational database:

```
Part
  - PartId
  - Name
  - ...more fields..

PartRelations
  - ParentPartId (PK)
  - ChildPartId (PK)
```

Using that schema, you could easily build massive hierarchies of parts, storing the part information a single time, and then just storing the relationship of parent part to child part.

You could further add the attribute model to this to allow your parts to have all different properties

```
PartAttribute
   - PartId
   - Attribute
   - Value
```

Attribute, could further be broken down if you wanted into another table Attribute

```
Attribute
   - AttributeId
   - AttributeName
   - ..datatype?.. (for pretty formatting logic or other..)
```

Then in the PartAttribute table, you could use AttributeId rather than Attribute. In practice, I've found that simply using a string rather than an attribute table that lists them all out is a bit easier for coding and just as easy to maintain

You could use a document database, but because the pieces are so related, I'm not sure it's a good fit, I'm sure some people might disagree with me though.

Comment: The attributes are used elsewhere in the system for other purposes, so your Attribute table suggestion isn't really going to work. I see where you're going, though.